# Make GraphQL/Prisma fields private/not able to be queried

Tags: postgresql, graphql, prisma

I'm using Prisma ORM with GraphQL.
I've got a user type, and for obvious reasons, I don't want the `password` field able to be queried. Is there any way to do this, either in Prisma, or GraphQL (or PostgreSQL)?

Comment: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/database-features#misc - not supported, yet ? https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/upgrade-guides/upgrade-from-graphcool#implementing-an-api-server-including-authentication--authorization

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can use [select](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/select-fields#select-specific-fields) to fetch the fields that you require and omit the ones that need to be private.

There's a request [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3636) for the same that will allow to exclude specific fields.